Mac dotnet: sdk Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000C
Recently I was trying to learn game development using Unity. However, when I open the C# script using the VS Code, it gives me the following error:

Found installed dotnet location "/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet" to load projects.
.NET SDK was resolved to /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet, but it failed to run. It is possible the installation of the .NET is corrupted, or not properly signed, or has no permission to run.

So, I tried to troubleshoot it by checking whether the installation is correct.
When I run dotnet --info, the dotnet information was printed successfully but the first line in the return is "Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000C".
I want to know how to resolve this error so that I can set the dotnet correctly and use VS Code for the development.

I'm using a Macboook Air (M1) running MacOS 15.

Alright, after hours of researching and trial-n-error. Finally, I fixed the issue by re-enabling the SIP back on. Now the error is gone and the VS Code works perfectly.
